# How insert encrypted value with DES into Postgresql DB?

Tags: python, psycopg2, des

I am using pyDes and psycopg2 Python library for save encrypted password into a PostgreSql database. 
For a given password, the corresponding DES value is not printable. If i try to execute the following query

```
INSERT INTO users (id,name,pwd,pass) VALUES ('0101','asino','asinello','?\xa5\x9aO\xbd\x10\xa3\x85\xfa6\xf8_\xfb\x91\x95\xe2')
```

I have the following error:
psycopg2.DataError: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xa5

I tried to use repr function but it doesn't work.
I think the error is that the encrypted password is not recognized by the UTF8 encoding.
How can I insert this data into the database?

Answer (score 0):

1. You shouldn't use DES for anything.  It is obsolete and recommended against.
2. You shouldn't store encrypted passwords unless you actually need to decrypt them.  For any sort of login system, you should use `bcrypt`
3. Your `insert` problem is mostly likely due to the fact that you're trying to store the encrypted, binary, data.  You probably forgot to encode the encrypted value to a base64 string.